# How to use jquery in non-react javascript on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-on-rails

I've recently incorporated The [react_on_rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) (NOT `react-rails`) Gem into my rails 4.2 code base.

I want to introduce new react components into an app that already has a fair amount of javascript code.

I ran the "hello world" generator for [react on rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) which, among other things, commented out the `//= require jquery` line from my `application.js` -- as a result of this my pre-existing coffeescript (which depended on `jquery` being present) no longer works. But the new generated demo `hello world` react components do work.

When i comment out the added `//= require vendor-bundle` and `//= require app-bundle` lines from my `application.js` and add back in the `//= require jquery` lines -- the opposite happens, the react components stop working but the pre-existing coffeescript works again.

My question is -- how do i set things up so that BOTH work? That is, that the new react components work, AND the pre-existing coffeescript (that relies on jquery) works as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the generator, so I'm not sure what all it contains.  But I do have the react-rails gem and jquery working in a bunch of my apps, so here's what my imports look like;

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require react
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react_ujs
```

Comment: I'm using [react_on_rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) not `react-rails`, react_on_rails uses webpack and a generally more node.js-centric setup. Unfortunately your code didn't work for me :(

Comment: Derp.  Ignore me then.